# How to collect Serial data via Python Telnet Class

Tags: python, oop, telnet

I have a simple class I modeled representing a Power Supply that I will be remotely connecting to via a telnet session. The class has various methods including connecting to the Power Supply, turning on/off the Power Supply, and adjusting its voltage. I am trying to add a method that will allow me to collect the output voltage data as long as it is turned on and a connection is established. As an attempt, I have implemented the `GetAllData` method. The method uses a while loop where the condition is to run the while loop until the status of the Power Supply is set to on. I'd like to be able to break out of the method/while loop once the power supply is commanded off via the `TurnOff()` method. Unfortunately, once the while loop has stared, it is impossible for it to break out. Can anybody recommend a better way I can implement what I am trying to do? here is my class below:

```
import os
import telnetlib

class PowerSupply():

    # ---------------------------------- #
    def __init__(self,port_no,my_name):
        self.Status = "Off"
        self.Port = port_no
        self.Name = my_name
        self.tn = None
        self.HOST = "192"
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def TurnOn(self):
        onCommand = "OUT 1\r"

        if self.Status == "ON":
            print "I'm already on"
        else:
            self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet(self.HOST,self.Port)
            self.tn.write(onCommand)
            self.Status = "ON"
            print "I am now on"
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def TurnOff(self):
        offCommand = "OUT 0\r"
        self.tn.write(offCommand)
        self.tn.close()
        print "I am now off"
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def SetVoltage(self,volts):
        voltageCommand = "PV" + " " + str(volts) + "\r"
        self.tn.write(voltageCommand)
    # ---------------------------------- #  
    def GetAllData(self):
        while(self.Status == "ON"):
            self.tn.write("DVC?\r")
            all_data = self.tn.read_some()
            vdc = all_data.split(',')
            vdc = vdc[0]
            print vdc
```